# Adding Header and footer to a docbook

Tags: xslt, docbook

I have a multi chapter docbook documentation. It is converted to HTMLHelp with xslproc the XSL\xsl\htmlhelp\htmlhelp.xsl file.

I need to add a footer and header to the generated HTML pages. I am a newbie about docbook (using it in a simple fashion so far) and XSL. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of named templates you can override for adding your own headers/footers. For comprehensive instructions, see section ["HTML headers and footers"](http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/HTMLHeaders.html) in the excellent [*DocBook XSL: The Complete Guide*](http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/index.html) by Bob Stayton.

By default, the HTML Help stylesheet disables the usual automatically generated navigation headers by setting the [`suppress.navigation`](http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/doc/html/suppress.navigation.html) parameter to 1.